# Salesforce Pyforce replacement

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am pulling cases/tickets in Salesforce and responding to each case via email.

I had been doing this using Pyforce but it is no longer compatible so I need an alternative.  I am using simple salesforce to login and query all the tickets but I can't find a way to respond on the ticket via email.

Previously I was using sendEmail(). Does anyone know of an alternative to this?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what exactly is incompatible? API version too old? You should be able to change it yourself in https://github.com/salesforce-python-client/pyforce/blob/c2b4316699a843051765cff64f660e773419a73d/pyforce/xmlclient.py#L31 ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PyForce uses SOAP API which well, all cool kids moved on to REST API. SOAP has dedicated [sendEmail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm)() call. You might still be able to hand-craft the matching XML message and send it using credentials obtained from simple-salesforce...

But have a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm, it looks like it'd be a straightforward insert operation?